# tap gesture not working on iOS 13.4 on textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

for some reason iOS 13.4 added buttonMaskRequired on its UITapGestureRecognizer class
can anyone explain how to use it? because i want to test if it causes the tap gesture on my textfield not working, now i need to long tap which is not good user experience. on the earlier version 13.3.1, tap gesture normally work. for example in the past version of iOS this code works as it is: (iOS SWIFT)

```swift
let tap2 = TouchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UpdateProfile.onCLickTextField(_:)))
tap2.delegate = self

if UserData.email == nil || UserData.email.isEmpty {
    tap2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
}

email.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)
email.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

it always work. not until iOS 13.4. and then i saw this change.[image]

can anyone explain how it works? and how to use it? thanks. sorry for my english.

Comment: where did you declare `tap2`? why you set `tap2.delegate = self`, where did you use this delegate? could you please share more code for better explanation please?

Comment: I suppose it's for Mac Catalyst and perhaps iPadOS with a mouse.